# Using or converting Lambert coordinates in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, coordinates

I'm trying to make an interactive map of Puerto Rico using the D3 JavaScript API.
However, the coordinate system that the Puerto Rico government uses is an old Lambert Coordinate
system. Is D3 capable of handling such coordinates? Is there a specific projection
that handles them? (I've looked through the projections wiki and couldn't find anything
useful.) If not, is there anything I can do to convert the coordinates to standard
longitude/latitude?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to use a desktop GIS such as [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) to convert the coordinates to something D3 can handle out of the box. You could make a custom projection, but that is likely to be more involved, especially if you need to do it only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the projection you have is part of the [State Plane Coordinate System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_Plane_Coordinate_System)  of 1983, defined on page 72 of [this NOAA PDF](http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PUBS_LIB/ManualNOSNGS5.pdf). You can also find it by searching for [“puerto rico”](http://spatialreference.org/ref/?search=puerto+rico) on [spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/) (e.g., [EPSG:2866](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2866/)).

You can **use [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to reproject your shapefile to latitude and longitude** by specifying the [EPSG:4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/) ([WGS84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System)) target projection. For example, to generate GeoJSON in spherical coordinates from your projected shapefile, you can say:

```
ogr2ogr \
    -f GeoJSON \
    -t_srs EPSG:4326 \
    output.json \
    input.shp
```

Once you have it the geometry in latitude and longitude, refer to any of the D3 geo examples to see how to display your shapefile in a projection of your choice.

Alternatively, you can **display it as-is using the projected coordinates**. See the [projected TopoJSON example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5557726) for more details, but the short of it is that you can use the [`topojson` command-line tool](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference) to create a [TopoJSON](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson) file in projected coordinates. Then you don’t have to reproject at all! For example, if you want to display it in a 960x500 space:

```
topojson \
    --width 960 \
    --height 500 \
    --margin 20 \
    -o output.json \
    -- input.shp
```

(You can even add a `-s .25` argument to simplify the geometry to the screen resolution, which is useful for saving space and improving rendering speed.)

Lastly, if you do end up reprojecting to latitude and longitude, but you still want to display Puerto Rico in its official state plane projection, you can define that projection using `d3.geo.conicConformal`, the Lambert conic conformal projection:

```
var projection = d3.geo.conicConformal()
    .scale(5000) // adjust to your liking
    .rotate([66 + 26/60, 0])
    .center([0, 17 + 50/60])
    .parallels([18 + 2/60, 18 + 26/60])
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
```

See also the [project to bounding box example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4707858) to see how to compute the scale and translate automatically for a feature of interest.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I followed your alternate option as it is more efficient and went through the projected TopoJSON example. Everything went beautifully. Thank you so much.